# Streaming webcam to my webpage

Tags: streaming, webcam

I am trying to build a webpage that shows the video of a webcam on live. 
Right now, I have no webcam, so I'll have to buy one. I don't mind how much it costs, I just want it working with a good resolution (at least 720p).

I don't know which kind of camera I should buy and which programming language is better for that (if it's possible I would prefer not to use Flash).

Can you help me?

Sorry for my bad English, I'm trying to improve ;)
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show in a webpage, you can use `IP-Camera`. They cost a little more, but they can serve their images as independent network node. They also supports voice and live compression (H264 and MPEG4).

Best brand is `Axis`, but there are lots of options.

For Axis camera models, adding view to page would be as easy as add this item to your page:

```
<img src='http://192.168.1.20/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi'>
```

It works for most browser, not IE. For IE, they have support as well [here](http://www.axis.com/techsup/cam_servers/tech_notes/live_video_medium.htm).

Comment: Thank you for the information! If I buy an IP-camera how can I connect the webpage with it?

Comment: I updated the post to add an example for Axis camera. There are a lot of them with all range of prices. For you usage, it's better option

Comment: Thank you a lot! It's very easy!
I suppose that if I want to use it in a server that isn't in the same LAN I will have to use a static IP.
Is this code working for other IP-cameras?

Comment: No, just Axis camera. Some other cameras do have MJPEG support. You need to check the manual and online resources.